# Are media queries still used

Tags: media-queries

Are media queries still compilant to manage the ui on different devices or something else is used now ?  If so could someone help me with some good resources to learn them ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are used very frequently in (and some would say one of the foundations of)  responsive design for determining screen size break points.

Consider the following resources:

- http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/
- http://alistapart.com/topic/responsive-design
- http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/
- http://mediaqueri.es/

An example:

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .my_div{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .my_div {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .my_div {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
  }
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

These are some common media queries for standard devices.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
```

It also helps a lot to find your target by taking a look at [stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop+mobile+tablet-resolution-ww-yearly-2012-2013-bar).

[image: Top 14 desktop, mobile and tablet screen resolutions from 2012 to 2013]

If you want to test some device physically you can check [here](http://www.testdevice.theprotokol.com/).